# Rails 3: How should I set up this has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, has-many

Trying to figure out the best way to set up my models. Here's what I've going going on...

Models: `Dog`, `Video`, `Photo`, `User`

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
  has_many :photos
  belongs_to :user
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
  belongs_to :user
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
  has_many :videos
  has_many :photo
end
```

Should I do `has_many :through` and a polymorphic?

In my previous iteration of this, I had `DogPhoto` and `DogVideo` models, but seems like I could have a single `DogItem` model that's polymorphic.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a polymorphic association would apply here, and it would be a good practice. However, i think that you should have a new model like DogMedia or so, that would be the polymorphic association.

This way a user has a dog and a dog has many DogMedias. A DogMedia is a polymorphic association that can either be a photo, video or anything else you like :)

You could use has many through to get dogmedia for a user's dog directly yes. Something like :

```
User has many dog_medias through dog  (plain language)
```

or just traverse it through dog :

```
user.dog.dog_media
```

If you do the latter, you can even create a Media instead of DogMedia class, create a delegate and execute the neat :

```
user.dog_media
```

directly ( The law of demeter : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter )